# Issue using turbo_flask to refresh html content on python

Tags: python, jinja2

I'm trying to run a thread function ***update_load*** every 5 second using python to refresh Html content using flask turbo and jinja

**My issue**

i'm not able to reload the Html using turbo.push it give me this error from browser console:

https://cdn.skypack.dev/-/@hotwired/turbo@v7.2.2-RBjb2wnkmosSQVoP27jT/dist=es2020,min/@hotwired/turbo.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

**My code**

```
import random
import sys
import threading
import time
from flask import Flask, render_template
from turbo_flask import Turbo

app = Flask(__name__)
turbo = Turbo(app)

@app.route('/')
def index():
return render_template('index.html')

def update_load():
with app.app_context():
    while True:
        time.sleep(5)
        turbo.push(turbo.replace(render_template('loadavg.html'), 'load'))

@app.before_first_request
def before_first_request():
threading.Thread(target=update_load).start()
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved in this [issues/42](https://here%20https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/turbo-flask/issues/42)